# using libimagequant in android ndk

Tags: android-ndk

Has anyone used successfully the quantizer "libimagequant" library in android NDK?

The library can be found here: http://pngquant.org/lib

The problem I'm facing is when calling liq_image_create_rgba, the compiler complains with:

**Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
* liq_image_create_rgba(*, void *, int, int, double)
'**

Seems the problem is the first parameter (liq_attr). But I can't understand why is complaining and how to solve it.

```
liq_attr* liqAttr = liq_attr_create();
liq_image* liqImage = liq_image_create_rgba(liqAttr, reinterpret_cast<void*>(bitmapPixels), width, height, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

In my version of libimagequant.c the liq_image_create_rgba function is declared as follows:

```
LIQ_EXPORT liq_image *liq_image_create_rgba(liq_attr *attr, void* bitmap, int width, int height, double gamma)
```

The first parameter is a liq_attr *, maybe yours is missing its pointer type?

Comment: Please move the second half of this answer into a comment, delete it, or ask your own question.

Comment: Making a comment was my first try but it seems I don't have enough reputation for that

Comment: Sorry about that, I created my own question [over here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25116305/use-pngquant-lib-libimagequant-in-android-ndk)