# Use pngquant lib (libimagequant) in Android NDK

Tags: android, c++, c, android-ndk

I am trying to use the png quantization library at pngquant.org/lib in my Android project using the NDK r10 (64bit) on OS X.

I am making progress in compiling the library. The problem I have now is that the size_t type cannot be resolved. I tried including the following folder:

```
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(NDK_TOOLCHAIN)/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9/include
```

but that does not help.

I would be really interested in an empty working Android project with pngquant included.

Any help is really appreciated.

NB sorry for changing the question, but the original question I asked had some incorrect facts in it.

Comment: Well if you're compiling a C++ source file you can't use C-specific flags, and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough information to directly solve your specific problem, are you trying to use the standalone toolchain ?

When building for Android, since you have more than one architecture to target and the toolchain is a bit complex, it's better to use the ndk-build script from the NDK.

I've made a project here that you can integrate to your Android project directory: https://github.com/android-native-libraries/pngquant-android

The original library is using configure script but instead of extending these I've rewritten NDK Makefiles to directly compile all the lib sources, with the same cflags (openmp, sse...)

Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

SRC_PATH := pngquant/lib

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := imagequant
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
    $(SRC_PATH)/blur.c \
    $(SRC_PATH)/libimagequant.c \
    $(SRC_PATH)/mediancut.c \
    $(SRC_PATH)/mempool.c \
    $(SRC_PATH)/nearest.c \
    $(SRC_PATH)/pam.c \
    $(SRC_PATH)/viter.c 

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := pngquant/lib

LOCAL_CFLAGS += -O3 -fno-math-errno -funroll-loops -fomit-frame-pointer -Wall -std=c99 -fopenmp
LOCAL_LDFLAGS += -fopenmp

ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),x86)
    LOCAL_CFLAGS += -mtune=atom -msse -mfpmath=sse -mssse3 -DUSE_SSE=1
endif

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

You can extend this Android.mk file to add your own native library with your sources, that are using libimagequant:
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
    LOCAL_MODULE := yourlib
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES := yoursources.c
    LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := pngquant/lib
    LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := imagequant

```
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -O3 -fno-math-errno -funroll-loops -fomit-frame-pointer -Wall -std=c99 -fopenmp
LOCAL_LDFLAGS += -fopenmp

ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),x86)
    LOCAL_CFLAGS += -mtune=atom -msse -mfpmath=sse -mssse3 -DUSE_SSE=1
endif

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to use this library with default settings, I've made a [simple Android library](https://github.com/ndahlquist/pngquant-android) that may suit your purposes.

In your build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.ndahlquist:pngquant-android:0.2'
}
```

In your Android app:

```
File inputPngFile = getYourPng();
File outputPngFile = getOutputFile()
new LibPngQuant().pngQuantFile(inputFile, outputFile);
```